# Queries Confusing. New To MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm new to databases. I recently Started a course and was able to build and insert into my own tables. however i am stuck at the queries part of the exercise. i read the chapters and sites which relate to it but it was just out of my understanding.

This is a link to my code. I am using mySQL console from WampServer

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jvsc2uv88pkybzb/DB%20Code.txt?dl=0

And these are the queries in the exercise

5) Write a query that selects all the jobs for a particular customer.
6) Write a query that selects the jobs that David Garcia has worked on.
7) Write a query that selects all the owner and addresses for bathroom installation jobs.
8) Write a query that counts the number of jobs that need a kitchen sink.
9) Write a query that selects the customer names and addresses for all the jobs that require fittings from Dennis Bathrooms

Comment: You should at least *try* to write the queries. You certainly know how to select *all* jobs? And you know what a WHERE clause is for? You know how to JOIN tables? If you are not even able to write query 5, then you missed the most basic lesson already. Ask your teacher to explain it once more or look up an online tutorial on SQL.

Answer (score 0):

for 5)Select * from Job where CustomerID="Customer_id"